# How to specify parameters in an SQL query using spring's jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

How would i specify the value for the 'age' parameter in the following jdbctemplate example?

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER where age = ? ";

    List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    List<Map> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
    for (Map row : rows) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setCustId((Long)(row.get("CUST_ID")));
        customer.setName((String)row.get("NAME"));
        customer.setAge((Integer)row.get("AGE"));
        customers.add(customer);
    }

return customers;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use the [queryForList()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method taking arguments as argument, for example:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, theAge);
```

Learn to read API documentation (and documentation in general). That's how you learn.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the documentation but got a bit confused because it works differently for when retrieving a single row or multiple rows which is slightly different compared to standard JDBC.